# cannot implicitly convert type int to system collections generic list<int>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

How do I set the new ProductOrderDetail object with a list of ProductIds and a list of OrderIds? Right now I'm getting error

> cannot implicitly convert type int to system collections generic `List<int>`.

My code looks something like this:

```
internal class ProductOrderDetail
{
    public List<int> ProductIds { get; set; }
    public List<int> OrderIds { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<ProductOrderDetail> GetProductOrderDetail(
             IEnumerable<int> productIds,IEnumerable<int> OrderIds)
{
    var query = (from p in products
                join o in orders on p.productId equals o.product_id_fk
                where o.customerId_fk == this.CustomerId
                where productIds.Contains(p.productId)
                where orderIds.Contains(o.orderId)

                select new ProductOrderDetail()
                {
                    ProductIds = p.productId,
                    SubLobIds = o.orderId
                });

    return query;
}

var productIds = { 1, 2, 3 };
var orderIds = { 11154, 13157 };

ProductOrderDetail results = new ProductOrderDetail();
results = ProductOrderDetail(productIds,OrderIds);
```

For the problem I'm trying to solve, I thing the solution looks something like this:

```
select new ProductOrderDetail()
{
    ProductIds = select new list<int> { p.productId }.ToList(),
    SubLobIds = select new list<int> { o.orderId }.ToList()
});
```

This syntax doesn't work, but I know this is close.

Comment: you have a single product/order id and trying to put it in a list?

Comment: I suspect `ProductIds` and `OrderIds` should be `int`, not a list of.

Comment: No, it's a lists of ProductIds & OrderIds, matched that against a table and returning the list of matches.

Comment: Your method name has the same name as the class.  That's a bit confusing.  The method should have a verb in its name to indicate what it does, such as `GetProductOrderDetails`.

Comment: @Bill Yes, I see how you have it implemented.  I'm suggesting your model is incorrect.  I would expect a `ProductOrderDetail` to contain information for one product and one order, hence its name; and you would have a `List<ProductOrderDetail>`, each identifying one product/order pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to rework your model.  Your current model would have a list of one product id and one order id.  Why have a list containing one thing?  Won't you want to know which products are associated with which orders?

```
internal class ProductOrderDetail
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<ProductOrderDetail> GetProductOrderDetail(IEnumerable<int> productIds, IEnumerable<int> OrderIds)
{
    var query = (from p in products
                join o in orders on p.productId equals o.product_id_fk
                where o.customerId_fk == this.CustomerId
                where productIds.Contains(p.productId)
                where orderIds.Contains(o.orderId)
                select new ProductOrderDetail()
                {
                    ProductId = p.productId,
                    OrderId = o.orderId
                });

    return query;
}
```

Usage:

```
var productIds = { 1, 2, 3 };
var orderIds = { 11154, 13157 };

List<ProductOrderDetail> results = GetProductOrderDetail(productIds, OrderIds).ToList();
```

This gets you a list of product/order id pairs.